# How to fetch what is written in strong tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The `id` is `txtCatalog` and I actually need to fetch the text wildlife:

```js
var mylist = document.getElementById("txtCatalog");
var name = mylist.text;
document.write(name);
```

```html
<strong id="txtCatalog">WILDLIFE</strong>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("txtCatalog").innerText;`

Comment: Try using `innerText` if you don't expect HTML content inside `<strong>`. If you are sure that text will not be overridden by styles (may be hidden) you can `textContent` which is faster.

Comment: @RacilHilan Why is that? That makes not sense. `innerHTML` would need to swap out the div and trigger parsing of `domContent`.

Comment: `swap out the div` there is no div

Comment: @RacilHilan What makes you think that `innerHTML` is faster than `textContent`?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings (and @Bergi) You're right, for reading content `textContent` is slightly faster than `innerHTML`, both are noticeably faster than `innerText`. But your comment is more for writing content, then the difference becomes big between all three, `innerHTML` becomes the slowest while `textContent` remains the fastest. However, it's worth noting that `textContent` is not supported in IE<9, in case it's important to support those legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `text` property on the element, use the `innerHTML` property:

```js
var mylist = document.getElementById("txtCatalog");
var name = mylist.innerHTML;
document.write(name);
```

```html
<strong id="txtCatalog">WILDLIFE</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to get the value **Wildlife** from the  tag. If this is what you are looking for then you can go for this solution

```
document.getElementById('txtCatalog').innerText
```

This solution will might work for you.